# Git - Some commits can only be seen in "All Branches" where the only branch is master

Tags: git, bitbucket

We are using Git repository from Bitbucket.

A person from our team is ahead 6 commits from origin/master branch. Also when he push his commits, he can see everything is up-to-date but still ahead from origin/master.

His commits can only be seen when the "All Branches" are selected. If the master branch is selected his commits can not be seen.

[image: "master" branch is selected]

[image: "All Branches" is selected]

What is the reason for that? How could my friend do it? And most important how can we merge his commits to origin/master?

Comment: Do you and your friend each have your own repositories? Was one of them cloned/forked from the other?

Comment: Nope, the screenshots are taken from the same repository.

Comment: Did your friend create another branch (other than `master`) for his work? (If not, this is considered a good practice, and you should do so in the future.)

Comment: It appears that your friend has pushed a new branch or else has pushed a "headless" branch. For the later, you should probably create a new branch in your local repo and then push it to BitBucket.

Comment: Yes, it seems development in headless branch pushed to repository. It is interesting that repository allows some sort of actions. Also when my friend is pulled the repository into his workspace, he thought he has lost previous work. What I have done is: restored back to a previous commit before merge, than created a new branch, pushed it to repository, then merge the new branch into master branch, and deleted the extra branch. Now everything seems ok :)

Comment: Thanks Code-Apprentice, note that your comment can be accepted as correct answer if you add.

Comment: I edited my original answer. Please delete your comment to avoid confusing future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your friend has pushed a "headless" branch to the BitBucket repo. You need to create a new branch on this headless branch and merge it into `master`.